# Flink checkpoint is getting aborted

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am running Apache Flink mini cluster in Intellij.
Trying to setup a stream join where one stream is coming from kinesis source and other from jdbc.

When I am creating a datastream from table source like following :

```
 // Table with two fields (String name, Integer age)
 Table table = ...

 // convert the Table into an append DataStream of Row by specifying the class
 DataStream<Row> dsRow = tableEnv.toAppendStream(table, Row.class);
```

I am getting following info message in the stack tracke :

```
INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator    [] - Checkpoint triggering task 
 Soource ...  
job bcf73c5d7a0312d57c2ca36d338d4569 is not in state RUNNING but FINISHED instead. Aborting 
checkpoint.
```

Answer (score 0):

Flink checkpoints cannot happen if any of the job's tasks have run to completion. Perhaps your jdbc source has finished, and this is preventing any further checkpointing?

Comment: I have also configured a sink function for one other datastream.
However the sink function triggers on flink checkpointing
->  
public class clazz extends RichSinkFunction <clazz> implements CheckpointedFunction, CheckpointListener.  

I am trying to first sink the content of stream and then join the same to a datastream created from the table. When I run only the first sink function, it is working fine

Comment: That doesn't sound likely to cause this.

Comment: I am checkpointing after every 5 seconds. My JDBC source job is getting finished before that and when flink tries to checkpoint, getting this issue.

Comment: I did find this article
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-147%3A+Support+Checkpoints+After+Tasks+Finished

Comment: Is there a way around this ? is it possible to keep JDBC source refreshing, allowing flink to checkpoint ?

Comment: Which JDBC source are you using?

Comment: Using PostgresCatalog for creating Postgress JDBC source.

Comment: You might be happier with https://github.com/ververica/flink-cdc-connectors.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your parallelism Settings,
if your program's parallelism is greater than the source's parallelism, then some task will show completion because it doesn't have the data, and that would abort a checkpoint.